# Find a and b such that $ P(\sigma_*^2 < a\sigma ^2) =0.025$ and $ P(\sigma_*^2 > b\sigma ^2) =0.025$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing, variance

Let $X_1, X_2 ... X_n \text{ ~ } N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$ be identically distributed and consider the estimate 
$$ \sigma_* ^{2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2 $$
for the variance.

Find number $a$ and $b \in \mathbb{R} $  such that $ P(\sigma_*^2 < a\sigma ^2) =0.025$ and  $ P(\sigma_*^2 > b\sigma ^2) =0.025$

This is all that was given in the question, and I'm not sure how to approach it, I was thinking of using the equation for $\sigma ^2$ but its the same (or I think it is) as $ \sigma_* ^{2}$. This question is in relation to hypothesis testing and so far I've looked at z and t tests, but I'm not sure how i can standardise these two values. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma_*^2$ is a random variable, being a function of the random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$.  Its probability distribution is derived from the sampling distribution, and your goal is to determine what this distribution is.  Note that $$X_i - \mu \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0, \sigma^2)$$ and $$\frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$$ is a pivotal quantity.  So $$\Pr[\sigma_*^2 < a\sigma^2] = \Pr\left[\frac{\sigma_*^2}{\sigma^2} < a\right],$$ and since $$\frac{\sigma_*^2}{\sigma^2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2$$ is the mean of $n$ IID standard normal random variables, $$n\frac{\sigma_*^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_n.$$  How would you find the constant $a$ based on this information?

Comment: Should there be two possible cases : i) when $\mu$ is known and ii) when $\mu$ is unknown???